# Remove the noise from ImageMagick transformation pipeline

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I am trying to "simplify" an image with **ImageMagick** by converting it to gray-scale and using an oil paint filter group larger parts that seem to be equal, e.g. clouds, grassland...

My source image for the example is:

[image: Source image for the example]
(from tmdb: http://www.themoviedb.org/movie/122-the-lord-of-the-rings-the-return-of-the-king)

When using IrfanView for Windows, I do the following steps:

- Reduce to 16 colors gray scale
- Apply oil paint effect with the maximum value of 255

This is the resulting image (replaced lower color with floodfill, perfect!):
[image: Resulting image]

It's exactly how I want it (maybe some parameters need tuning). When I try to make the same result with ImageMagick, I hacked this:

```
convert -monitor lotr2.jpg +dither -quantize gray -colors 8 \
        -paint 6 lotr_oilpaint.jpg
```

But no matter what I am trying, there is a really awful amount of noise in the image. I tried the [mode filter](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#mode) and it helped a little bit by removing some noise but it seems to add some noise in other parts.

It's far away from the IrfanView solution, generating really solid areas of the same color which can be flood filled with no problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had a quick shot at your challenge... this is the first command I tried:

```
convert                               \
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/6iX53.jpg \
  -colorspace gray                    \
  -colors 16                          \
  -paint 8                            \
   6iX53.png
```

As you can see, I skipped the `-floodfill +X+Y red` parameter for now...

Here is my result:

[image: Result]

It looks already rather close to yours. It contains 10 different colors:

```
identify -format '%k\n' 6iX53.png

 10
```

To successfully do a `-floodfill` when there is some 'noise' in the image, you can add a `-fuzz X%`-factor to the command. So let's try that with `-fuzz 3%`:

```
convert                               \
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/6iX53.jpg \
  -colorspace gray                    \
  -colors 16                          \
  -paint 8                            \
  -fuzz 3%                            \
  -fill red                           \
  -floodfill +1+438 '#030303'         \
   6iX53-floodfilled.png
```

Result:

[image: 2nd Result]

Maybe by playing with some of the parameters I used, you can get the result closer to what you want...

Comment: Thanks, saving as losless png was the solution. Jpg introduced further lossy compression and noise, sometimes you no longer see the wood for the trees :(

Comment: @Tobias: That was main reason for me to use PNG :-)